# Bazaar only ssh, is bzr_ssh_path_limiter secure? or should I use sftp?

Tags: ssh, sftp, bazaar

I would like to allow some users to **read/write**  **Bazaar** repositories on a server using ssh.

I read about using [**bzr_ssh_path_limiter**](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.dev/en/admin-guide/security.html#using-ssh) (with restricted ssh keys) which is a nice tool and seems to do the work. I've also seen that it is possible to use **sftp** for bazaar.

- Is bazaar ("bzr serve") secure enough that the client cannot execute any shell commands?
- Should I use sftp? Can I restrict access to a folder? and disallow shell commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, while I am inclined to trust the combination of bzr serve and ssh, there is still a lot less "moving parts" in an [OpenSSH SFTP chroot](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590). Hence, a lot less thing which could go wrong, or which could be exploited.

The potential problem with running bazaar against SFTP is that is relatively slow. Whatever that is a problem or not depends on what kind of repositories you will be sharing. Yet, if you are worried about security, then I think you should at least try the SFTP-chroot solution, to see whatever it is feasible or not.